# Why does non-pure virtual method have to be defined in base class?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

In this particular case, why do I have to define the non-pure virtual method in the base class in order to avoid a linker error?

This gives a linker error:

```
class A
{
  public:
  virtual ~A(){}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual void bar();
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
  void foo()
  {
  }
  void bar()
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Output:

```
/tmp/cc5E8Tit.o: In function `A::~A()':
:(.text._ZN1AD2Ev[_ZN1AD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for
A' /tmp/cc5E8Tit.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x10): undefined reference
to `typeinfo for A' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if i define the bar method in class `A` it links ok:

```
class A
{
  public:
  virtual ~A(){}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual void bar(){}
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
  void foo()
  {
  }
  void bar()
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

... no linker error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **10.3 Virtual functions**
>
> 11 A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is required (3.2).

It's OK to define a pure virtual function but it is not necessary.

It is necessary to define a virtual function if it is declared but not declared as pure virtual.

It's good that the linker complains even though the language does not require it to.

Answer (score 5):

**R Sahu** already provided standard quote related to this, I will provide slightly longer explanation why error happens — sometimes you can get away with not defining functions if they are not used, but not in this case.

Virtual functions are always used. Their *address* is used in virtual tables which are built for each class with virtual functions and which are used for dynamic dispatch.

Linker emits an error, because base class `A` constructor sets up pointer to base class virtual table, virtual table contains pointer to `bar` and linker cannot find definition of `bar` member function to find its address.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the definition itself. A function is pure virtual if it is not defined. Then, if you don't flag it as pure virtual, you have to define it. It's a constraint of the `C++` language.

Comment: Why have the function to be defined when it is not called?

Comment: "*A function is pure virtual if it is not defined*" is not correct. A function is pure virtual if it has been declared pure virtual. A pure virtual function can have a definition (but doesn't need to have).